# Arduino nano / uno analog pin

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, atmega328

I'm working on a project where I need 7 analog pins.
I read the datasheet of Ardnuino Uno : 6 analog pins available.
So I decided to use an arduino mega with 16 analog pin available.
Then I saw the arduino nano had 8 analog pins.
But when I read the datasheet, both arduino uno and nano use Atmega328
In my final project, I will not use the board but only the pdip chip (analog pins are from pin number 23 to 28). 
Is it possible to "convert" another pin of the pdip to be an analog pin ?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to stick with DIP parts, add an external ADC such as MCP3008, a 4-channel ADC with 10-bit resolution and fast SPI interface. Available at Digikey, easy to read from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The [datasheet of the ATmega328P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf)
states it has:

> - 8-channel 10-bit ADC in TQFP and QFN/MLF package
> - 6-channel 10-bit ADC in PDIP Package

If you want to use a bare chip, it won't be possible with a PDIP
package.

Answer (score 0):

A Nano and some ProMinis have all 8 analog input pins available from the 32-pin TQFP Atmega328P package. An Uno only has 6 of the 8 available in the 28-pin DIP package. Instead of the bare 28-pin DIP, use one of the 32-pin TQFP parts, on a breakout board, or as a packaged 'system' board; a Promini is the 328P with resonator and voltage regulator, connect to it with external FTDI module for programming/debugging; the Nano which goes a step further and adds a USB interface chip.